# ¿Como reemplazar el valor de un Textview, que esta dentro de una tabla en android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Espero me puedan apoyar con esta duda, por mas que busco no encuentro la forma de reemplazar el valor que tengo en un `textview` que se encuentra dentro de una tabla dependiendo lo que se seleccione en un `spinner`.

Nota: La tabla se genera de acuerdo al tamaño de una lista.

```
  table = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabla);

for( int i = 0; i<frutasListaa.size(); i++){//filas frutasListaa.get(i).getIdequivalente2()+
                lista.add(frutasListaa.get(i).getAlimento()+" "+frutasListaa.get(i).getCantidad()+" "+frutasListaa.get(i).getUnidad()+" = "+frutasListaa.get(i).getCalorias()+" kcal");           

                //--------------TABLAAAA   ----------------------//
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());//frutasListaa.get(i).getIdTbalimentos()+
                table.addView(tableRow);                 

                     tvAlimentos = new TextView(getContext());
                     tvPorcion = new TextView(getContext());
                     tvCalorias = new TextView(getContext());                       

                    tvAlimentos.setText(frutasListaa.get(i).getAlimento());
                    tableRow.addView(tvAlimentos);
                    tvPorcion.setText("  "+frutasListaa.get(i).getCantidad()+" "+frutasListaa.get(i).getUnidad());
                    tableRow.addView(tvPorcion);
                    tvCalorias.setText("  "+frutasListaa.get(i).getCalorias());
                    tableRow.addView(tvCalorias);
}
```

**El siguiente es un spinner:**

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista);
                spdesayuno1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

El layout es el siguiente:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableLayout>
```

Aqui se muestra el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano gracias por su atención.

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado para modificar el valor del `TextView`.

Comment: Como nota adicional, no es una tabla, es un adapter

Comment: Si le asignas un background al TextView de color rojo. Se ve? Creo que puede ser que no estas asignandole al TextView un `width` y `heigth`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el Textview? ¿Se muestra en pantalla? ¿Se muestra con otro valor o no muestra nada? ¿Has probado  poniendo un texto arbitrario en él para probar que no sea un problema de la obtención del texto que quieres mostrar?... A tu pregunta le faltan detalles importantes para la comprensión del problema.

Comment: El TextView esta dentro de un for de tipo objeto que se incrementa de acuerdo al tamaño de la lista y esta a su vez se inserta en el layout

Comment: No he logrdo modificar el TextView ya que es dinamico puesto que se crean filas de acuerdo al tamaño de la lista. Es aqui donde no se como modificarlo ya que no tiene un id especifico paa valor cada valor.

Comment: Se me ocurre que al momento de agregar el view le agregues un Tag, de esta manera podrás buscar y editar ese view mediante ese Tag. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

Comment: No me queda, lo que hice para solucionarlo más rápido fue crear una listview. Lo malo es el tamaño de letra que no puedo modificar ya que la quiero pequeña.